# Show Documentation popup on mouse move in Android Studio not working over the latest Android Studio Version 2023.1.1.26

Tags: popup, documentation

I upgraded my android studio version to HedgeHog 2023.1.1.26 which is the latest version of the Android Studio by the date of 4/12/2023. Now I am facing a problem of documentation popup on mouse move over the Widgets. It appears on Ctrl + Q on window operating system. But I want to show the documentation of the widget on mouse move. Help me out.....

I tried from the stack overflow I many solution were given but those works only on the outdated version it doesn't appear in the latest version. I tried from "file>>Settings>>Editor>>General>>Code Completion" but it does not solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone else will need to fix it.
You can uncheck the Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | Support screen readers option.

Comment: Oh Brother thank you so much it solved my problem and now I am able to show documentation of the widget on mouse hover.